# SQL Server use SUM function based on rank

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following query -

```
SELECT sub.Name, sub.SizeGB, sub.DriveName,
RANK() OVER   
(PARTITION BY sub.DriveName ORDER BY sub.Name DESC) AS Rank
FROM
(
  SELECT NAME,
SUBSTRING(physical_name, 0, 2) AS DriveName,
SIZE * 8 / (1024*1024) AS SizeGB
FROM sys.master_files
WHERE database_id > 4
) as sub
GROUP BY sub.DriveName, sub.Name, sub.SizeGB
```

which gives me the below output

[image]

I want to find the space occupied by all the files on a particular drive. So the idea is to `SUM` the `SizeGB` column based on the `Rank` column. Is there a way to edit my current query to achieve the desired result.

The output should look like below -

[image]

Comment: what's the output you expect? Is it SUM of sizeGB based on the DriveName?

Comment: @kenean - Yes that's what I would like to have. Let me edit that into my question.

Comment: I don't understand what you want here. Do you want a running total for each drive or do you want the relevant total for the drive to be on every row?

Comment: I'm thinking you need SELECT DQ.DriveName, SUM(DQ.SizeGB) AS GB FROM (your exisitng query) DQ GROUP BY DQ.DriveName

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can aggregate again in an outer query to get a sum of the drive size. Using a PARTITIONED SUM will give you repeating values inside the partition window.

```
SELECT
    *,
    TotalSize=SUM(SizeGB) OVER (PARTITION BY DriveName)
FROM
(
    SELECT sub.Name, sub.SizeGB, sub.DriveName,
    RANK() OVER   
    (PARTITION BY sub.DriveName ORDER BY sub.Name DESC) AS Rank
    FROM
    (
      SELECT NAME,
    SUBSTRING(physical_name, 0, 2) AS DriveName,
    SIZE * 8 / (1024*1024) AS SizeGB
    FROM sys.master_files
    WHERE database_id > 4
    ) as sub
    GROUP BY sub.DriveName, sub.Name, sub.SizeGB
)AS X
```

OR as part of the detail query

```
    SELECT sub.Name, sub.SizeGB, sub.DriveName,
    RANK() OVER   
    (PARTITION BY sub.DriveName ORDER BY sub.Name DESC) AS Rank,
    SUM(SizeGB) OVER (PARTITION BY DriveName) AS TotalSize
    FROM
    (
      SELECT NAME,
    SUBSTRING(physical_name, 0, 2) AS DriveName,
    SIZE * 8 / (1024*1024) AS SizeGB
    FROM sys.master_files
    WHERE database_id > 4
    ) as sub
    GROUP BY sub.DriveName, sub.Name, sub.SizeGB
```

Answer (score 1):

```
This should retrieve it:

; with cte
AS
(SELECT  sub.Name, sub.SizeGB, sub.DriveName,
RANK() OVER   
(PARTITION BY sub.DriveName ORDER BY sub.Name DESC) AS Rank

FROM
(
  SELECT NAME,
SUBSTRING(physical_name, 0, 2) AS DriveName,
SIZE * 8 / (1024*1024) AS SizeGB
FROM sys.master_files
WHERE database_id > 4
) as sub
GROUP BY sub.DriveName, sub.Name, sub.SizeGB
)   
select * from cte  
JOIN (SELECT sum(sizeGB) sum, drivename dn from cte GROUP BY drivename) a 
ON a.dn = cte.drivename
```

Comment: This works for me too. I wish I could accept 2 answers. But Ross' answer provides more options. Anyways, thank you for your solution. Much appreciated! :)